# Publish solution file using Jenkins + Git HUb

Tags: c#, jenkins, github

```
cmd.exe /C ""C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\MSBuild" MyPro.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PublishProfile=DEV-BUILD.pubxml"
```

I'm not able to publish my sln file, Please help

Comment: Any errors? My msbuild.exe is not located in that folder on my dev box. What version of .Net are you targeting?

Comment: No Error,  Build succeeded but not able to see the published files.

Comment: Does the same command work on your machine?

Comment: no its not working